# ROS Arduino Subscribe to /cmd_vel

Tags: c++, arduino, ros

I am using ros_lib for the arduino to create a serial node using rosserial. I want to write a code that subscribes to the /cmd_vel topic and outputs the geometry_msgs/Twist message to a serial port (arduion mega, multiple serial ports).

Thanks in advance

```
#include <ros.h>
#include <std_msgs/String.h>
#include <std_msgs/Empty.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/Twist.h>

ros::NodeHandle  nh;

ros::Subscriber<geometry_msgs::Twist> sub("/cmd_vel", messageCb );

void setup()
{
  Serial1.begin(9600);
  nh.initNode();
  nh.subscribe(sub);
}

void loop()
{
  Serial1.println(sub.data);
  nh.spinOnce();
  delay(1);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Right now your question is too broad and unspecific, which makes it unlikely that someone will answer it. Please use the edit function to explain more what you already tried and where exactly you have a problem. See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is incomplete, when you do:

```
ros::Subscriber<geometry_msgs::Twist> sub("/cmd_vel", messageCb );
```

you are telling the ROS-Master the following:

please informe about the msgs onthe topic "**/cmd_vel**" and for that use the callback method: ***messageCb*** but you have no callback method in the code.... you are missing something like:

```
void messageCb(const std_msgs::String::ConstPtr& msg)
{
    Serial1.println("The turtle said:");
    Serial1.println(msg->data.c_str());
}
```